# Android itemizedOverlay's onTap action overrided

Tags: android, maps, itemizedoverlay, overlayitem

I have a class :

```
class MapItemizedOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> { 
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList items = new ArrayList();

    public MapItemizedOverlay(Context aContext, Drawable marker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
        context = aContext;
    }

    public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem item) {
        items.add(item);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return (OverlayItem) items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
       OverlayItem item = (OverlayItem) items.get(index);
       AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
       dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
       dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
       dialog.show();
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTap (final GeoPoint p, final MapView mapView) {
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,
                        p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
            String address = "";
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                    address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
            }   
            address.cancel();
            address.setText(address);
            address.show(); 
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I add some overlays on the map with the function:

```
private void initialiseOverlays() {
        // Create an ItemizedOverlay to display a list of markers
        Drawable defaultMarker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
        MapItemizedOverlay mapItemizedOverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(this, defaultMarker);

        mapItemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int) (12.345678 * 1E6), (int) (23.456789 * 1E6)), "Point 1", "some-random-text"));
        mapItemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int) (89.012345 * 1E6), (int) (67.890123 * 1E6)), "Point number 2", "more-random-text"));        
        // Add the overlays to the map
        mapView.getOverlays().add(mapItemizedOverlay);
      }
```

If only one of the onTap functions is defined everything works fine - I can either get the address if I click somewhere over the map or I can get a dialog with the place's title and content if I click on the icon over the place. 
But I want to have both of the functions working together, the application to detect if the click was over an empty place on the map or over a marker(the drawable set) and show it's information. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - had to include the:

```
if(super.onTap(p, mapView)) {
                return true;
            }
```

in the beginning of the `public boolean onTap (final GeoPoint p, final MapView mapView)` function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onTouch method

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, final MapView mapView) {
            final int action=event.getAction();
            final int x=(int)event.getX();
            final int y=(int)event.getY();
            result = false;
            if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                downPressed = true;
                drag = false;
/* here check for the items is null or not and then after get all the items 
   so if you click on map and on that place if the item on placed then it will
   check for the item hit other it refer the user click on map not on marker 

*/
                if(items!=null){
                    for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
                        OverlayItem item = items.get(i);
                        Point mp=new Point(0,0);
                        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(item.getPoint(), mp);
                        xDragTouchOffset=x-mp.x;
                        yDragTouchOffset=y-mp.y;
                        if (hitTest(item, marker, x-(mp.x-(xDragImageOffset+xDragTouchOffset*2)), y-(mp.y-((yDragImageOffset/2)+yDragTouchOffset)))) {
                            result = true;
                            markerIndex = i;
                            task_id = Long.parseLong(item.getTitle());
                            downPressed = false;
                            markerPressed = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
     // here user pressed and drag the downPressed set to false so it will indicate that user want to move the map and drag set to true;
            downPressed = false;
            drag=true;
        }
        else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    // if user not drag then this downPressed is true and it will return the screen and map coordinate
            if(downPressed){

                    tempPoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);
                    markerLat = tempPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1e6;
                    markerLng = tempPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1e6;
                    mapView.invalidate();
            }

            drag = false;
            downPressed = false;
        }
        return(result | super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView));
    }
```

here i can do this way hope you get some idea

Comment: What is the task from the `task.equals` in your code here.
The `onTouch method` is a bit unclear to me - could you please add some comments in the code above. Thanks.